# How to put bundle in arraylist with hashmap vallue in android

Tags: android

Hi friends 
 I am getting arraylist with hashmap like this `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()` I want to put it in bundle can anybody give example

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ArrayList is Serializable so you can put it into the bundle using [putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your browser on the Java SDK reference page for [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
2. Iterate over the array list using a [for each loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
3. Get your browser on the Java SDK reference page for [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)
4. For each [HashMap entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29), put the [entry key and the entry value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) in the bundle using the [Bundle.putString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method

You have everything you need here to learn how to do this basic stuff yourself easily.